# CodeIgniter3 - AWS S3 Bucket - PHP Warning coming but file get upload successfully

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**ISSUE DETAILS**
Files get uploaded successfully but, warning message is encountered

**ERROR**

```
Severity: User Warning

Message: S3::putBucket(acetute-uploads, private, ): [AccessDenied] Access Denied

Filename: libraries/S3.php
```

- KMS key is generated,
- Added in IAM ROLE user policy
- Bucket policy is added correctly

I guess the issue is related to policies

**Bucket Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Delete*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:List*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "KMSAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:REGION:111111111:key/xxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

**IAM User Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1488494182833",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1488493308547",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::11111111:user/USER"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:Delete*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::11111111:user/USER"
            },
            "Action": "s3:List*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help how can I remove warning!!

Comment: To troubleshoot this warning and one of the way to find root cause is to enable [AWS cloudtrail logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-tutorial.html) & enable [object-level logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-cloudtrail-events.html) for related S3 bucket. Later on, if not required you can disable this logging.

Comment: Thank you. Issue resolved. Issue was with Bucket policy

Comment: Please, if you have found the solution, add it as answer or edit your first question.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue resolved by changing bucket policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1488494182833",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1488493308547",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111:user/USER"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:Delete*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```